# how can I add boostrap dropdown without using rel="stylesheet"

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I am creating a website and I want to add some extra features. I have found this [template](https://codepen.io/atakan/pen/gqbIz), and I want to add some comboboxes(one full row for gender, three in one row for birthday).

I have found this bootstrap code for comboboxes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see the this code is using `rel="stylesheet"`, it is possible to change it? because the template from codepen.io uses another style.css file.

Now if it can be possible to change it, can you suggest something else for having comboboxes that match with the style of codepen.io template?

Comment: You can add multiple rel="styleshhet"

Comment: I try it and I have design promblems

Comment: For the tags, classes or IDs that are already used on style must be removed on another style. Especially the ones that are by tags e.g. body, b, div, span etc..

Comment: You just can't add it as is.

Comment: I will try it and I post my results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good idea to get rid of the bootstrap stylesheet because many tags with bootstrap classes will look out of place.  You can add other stylesheets to your webpage, as long as you put them after the bootstrap stylesheet.  This will make it so that the other stylesheet(s) will display everything they are supposed to, but the bootstrap stylesheet will style everything that the other stylesheet(s) do not specify.

Answer (score 1):

According to [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_rel.asp)

**The required rel attribute specifies the relationship between the current document and the linked document/resource.**

It cannot negatively impact your code, you have just trouble with CSS.

Also you should read [The Bootstrap's docs](https://getbootstrap.com/).